# How to debug patched method with unittest.mock

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing, python-mock

I have the following (simplified) FBV:

```
def check_existing_contacts(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        print('Function called')
        return mailgun_validate_email(request)
    return JsonResponse({"error": "Incorrect AJAX / GET request."}, status=400)
```

I want to test that the `mailgun_validate_email` function is called:

```
class TestCheckExistingContacts(TestCase):

    @patch('myapp.mailgun_validate_email')
    def test_new_contact(self, mock):
        client = Client()
        client.get('/check/', HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
        self.assertTrue(mock.called)
```

I am certain the test calls `mailgun_validate_email` as the `print('Function called')` displays in the console. However I get an assertion error that the `mock.called` is `False`.

Where am I going wrong / how can I debug this?

************ **UPDATE** *******************

When patching the function in the same module as the view, I get the following error:

```
class TestCheckExistingContacts(TestCase):

    @patch('[path to views.py with check_existing_contacts].mailgun_validate_email')
    def test_new_contact(self, mock):
        client = Client()
        client.get('/check/', HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
        self.assertTrue(mock.called)
```

Results in:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\tests\test_utils.py", line 123, in test_new_contact
    response = self.client.get('/validate/',
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 518, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 344, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **{
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 421, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 496, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 45, in process_response
    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
  File "\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py", line 267, in patch_vary_headers
    vary_headers = cc_delim_re.split(response['Vary'])
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 6):

1. If you did `from myapp import mailgun_validate_email` for `check_existing_contacts`, then you need to patch the reference in that module instead of `myapp`.
   E.g. if the import is in myapp/views.py, then patch `myapp.views.mailgun_validate_email`.
2. The view needs to return an instance of `HttpResponse` or one of its subclasses, same for `mailgun_validate_email` since you directly `return mailgun_validate_email(...)`.

```py
# @patch('myapp.mailgun_validate_email')                                     # Change this
@patch('myapp.views.mailgun_validate_email', return_value=JsonResponse({}))  # to this
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response aaron. [Not exactly what I've gone through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74436201/5675325) but it answers this question and helped me by providing reassurance that I was on the right path. Will give the bounty when possible! (+1)