# Django unittest function with redirect based on mock return_value

Tags: python, django, mocking, python-unittest, django-tests

I have a view function similar to

```
def my_function(request):
    session = create_something('some_random_string')
    return redirect(session.url, code=303)
```

To test it

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_app.views import my_function

class TestMyFunction(TestCase):

    @patch('my_app.views.create_something', return_value={
        "url": "https://tiagoperes.eu/"
    })
    def test_my_function(self, mock_create_something):
        response = self.client.get("/my-function/")
```

This gives

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'url'

This question is similar the following questions

- [Cannot redirect when Django model class is mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48720028/5675325) (in that I'm using the `redirect()` that takes dynamic values coming from the mocked function, so can also reach easily the error `TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes`)
- [How to debug patched method with unittest.mock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63073501/5675325) (in that without the `return_value` I'd get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to substitute the return_value in patch to use [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock)

```
@patch('my_app.views.create_something', return_value=MagicMock(url="https://tiagoperes.eu"))
```